# How to login and sign up through parse in ios

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am using parse server to login and send verify email in ios. The user registers itself on parse server. The email is send to the email id inputed and a link which  on clicking email is satisfied.
My problem is already existing user can't login again and i don't get to know has the user verified the mail or not
Please help! Any help would be appreciable.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The docs are very clear on this issue. I would suggest a review and implement a check of the current  PFUser. If nil, then you MUST fire up the login view controller. It is that simple, and the docs show this almost verbatim.  ;)  cheers!